# Safari extension for timed automagical tab switching. Does it exist? Can I create one?

Tags: safari-extensions

I can't find any extension that allows me to switch between open tabs every x seconds.....
Before I 'dive' into extension development I have to ask....:

- Is there a limitation in Safari's extensions system which would block the development of an auto tab switcher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible. The [extension API](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH17-SW1) gives you access to the [SafariBrowserTab](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariextensions/safaribrowsertab) class, which allows you to [activate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariextensions/safaribrowsertab/1635329-activate) a specific tab in a specific window. So adding an extension toolbar button that started/stopped the looped switching should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thnx. Turns out it was very straightforward indeed. Took me a couple of hours to get what I need.